# using "creating mobile apps with xamarin.forms" ebook with VS 2017

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Hey I am using  "creating mobile apps with xamarin.forms" ebook to learn about mobile app development but I am using the most current visual studio 2017. it is still worth it to learn from the ebook? Because it seem like the coding are different when I am inputting what the book ask me to type in the code.

If not, do you have any suggestions?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a fantastic book to learn Xamarin.forms (I've read the whole book twice).
Although This book is outdated, most of its examples [in Github](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples) have been updated 3 months ago.

My suggestion is to read this book. Also, read Xamarin's changes over this period on blogs.